# Is it a standard to add an auto increment column to a User Defined Table type?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i'm have collection in my client C# app which consist of the 5 columns. In the DB I have created a User defined table type (UDTT) of six columns. the first column is an autom increment which I will be using to fetch each row stored in it. table structure is `pSelCRSInfo`

```
    while(@cntr <= @pProgDuration)
    begin 

        select 
        @CRSID=CRSID,
        @YearNo=YearNo,
        @IsCompulsory=IsCompulsory,
        @EntDT=EntDT,
        @EmpID=EmpID 
        from @pSelCRSInfo where CntrNo=@cntr

        insert into DefaultCourses 
        (PRGID,CRSID,YearNo,IsCompulsory,EntDT,EmpID)
        values (@newPRGID,@CRSID,@YearNo,@IsCompulsory,@EntDT,@EmpID)
                                set @cntr = @cntr + 1
          end
```

in it's definition I have added

```
create type dbo.SelectedCourses
as table
(

    CntrNo int not null IDENTITY(1, 1), 
    CRSID int,
    YearNo int,
    IsCompulsory varchar(20),
    EntDT datetime,
    EmpID int
);
go
```

At the moment i'm struggling with how to pass 5 column collection to a collection that requires 6 column?

Typically do people create UDTT structures with auto increment columns to accept collections? because I could generate the numbers generated by the auto increment column from the client then send that with the collection

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends entirely on you. If auto-incremented values suit your purpose then definitely use them. I'd do it.

Answer (score 0):

so assume I have created a UDTT with a auto increment column, then still I should pass 6 column collection like the one below and leave the first column empty

```
//leave the first column empty
acd.dtCourses.Rows[CollCounter][0] = string.Empty    
acd.dtCourses.Rows[CollCounter][1] = dt.Rows[i][2];
acd.dtCourses.Rows[CollCounter][2] = dt.Rows[i][3];
acd.dtCourses.Rows[CollCounter][3] = dt.Rows[i][4];
acd.dtCourses.Rows[CollCounter][4] = DateTime.Today;
acd.dtCourses.Rows[CollCounter][5] = myAcedemics.EmpID;
```

`dtCourses` is a `datatable` to accept the collection and my `acd` is an object of the business class `Academics`